# nginx + fpm + subdirectory

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, directory, redirection, querystring

I have an nginx config that looks like this:

```
location ^~ /movies {
    alias /var/dp.cx/movies/current/public;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    try_files $uri /movies/index.php;

    location ~* \.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

This is a Laravel application, which works almost completely out of the box. However, there are a couple of small problems that I have with this configuration.

- Hitting `/movies` triggers a 404. Hitting `/movies/` works successfully.
- Hitting one of the pagination URLs (`/movies/test?page=2`) has no information from the querystring.

I'm not sure where I found this configuration, but it seems to be the closest thing to a "working" configuration I've ever found for nginx + fpm with a subdirectory URL.

Answer (score 0):

> Hitting /movies triggers a 404. Hitting /movies/ works successfully.

To solve it at the server-level... please add the following location block alongside the existing location block for movies...

```
location = /movies {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/movies/;
}
```

> Hitting one of the pagination URLs (/movies/test?page=2) has no
>   information from the querystring.

It is due to `try_files` line that doesn't pass the query string. To pass it, using the following `try_files` directive would work...

```
try_files $uri /movies/index.php$is_args$args;
```

Direct quote from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html ...

> $is_args - “?” if a request line has arguments, or an empty string
>   otherwise.

Comment: The `location = /movies` portion worked perfectly. Sadly, adding the `$is_args$args` triggers every page under `/movies` to return a 404.

Comment: Do you have a way to check if query string is received by the application? If yes and if the application indeed receives the query string, then the issue is with the application. Also, it is a good practice to upvote an answer that helped you. See https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers . Also, asking only one question at a time is a good practice. When two persons give a correct answer to just one question each, how would you choose the right answer?