# Execute PHP in subdirectory location Nginx

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I have the problem that when I want to run the PHP script it does not run

**File Structure**

```
/home/myapp/landing
* contact.php
* index.html
```

**NGINX Conf**

```
location / {
    alias /home/myapp/main;
}

location /landing-page {
     alias /home/myapp/landing/;

     location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/path/to/php.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          #also tried this
          #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/myapp/landing$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```

Comment: Also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/876733/nginx-fpm-subdirectory)

Comment: What's the rest of your nginx config?  What do the nginx debug logs say?